# Customize Journal Component in AEM Communities

Tags: ckeditor, aem, journal

is it possible to customize the Journal component to load the images and videos from DAM,

http://localhost:4502/content/community-components/en/journal.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a part of UGC?

Answer (score 1):

The Journal component does not come with a built in DAM browser therefore this cannot be done by OOTB components.

However, you can achieve similar result by exposing your published DAM via some public URL. Doing so, will allow the users to embed DAM images just like any other public image via a URL.